# Implementing a parallel version of Djikstra with openMP in C

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I plan to modify Djikstra algorithm in order to parallelize it with openMP. I know well that there is many solutions but I cannot change the code. Therefore I can only add pragmas instructions. Here is the given code.

```cs
double dijkstra(){

int shortest_dist;
int nearest_node;
double start,stop;

start = get_time();           //timer
tree[0] = 1;                  //tree table which contains every nodes  from the graph. If the value is 1 then the node has been treated

#pragma omp parallel private(shortest_dist, nearest_node) num_threads(nb) 
{

   #pragma omp for 
   for (int i = 1; i < num_nodes; i++)
       tree[i] = 0;

   //Get every distance of nodes connected to the beginning node
   #pragma omp for
   for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++)
       min_distance[i] = get_distance(0,i);


   for (int step = 1; step < num_nodes; step++ ){

      shortest_dist = INF;
      nearest_node = -1;

      #pragma omp parallel for reduction(min : shortest_dist) num_threads(nb)
      for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++){
          // find nearest node
          if ( !tree[i] && min_distance[i] < shortest_dist ){
              shortest_dist = min_distance[i];
              nearest_node = i;
          }
      }

      if ( nearest_node == - 1 ){
          fprintf(stderr,"Warning: Search ended early, the graph might not be connected.\n" );
          break;
      }

      #pragma omp single
      tree[nearest_node] = 1; 

      // Update every nodes
      for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++)
          if ( !tree[i] ){
              int d = get_distance(nearest_node,i);
              if ( d < INF )
                  if ( min_distance[nearest_node] + d < min_distance[i] )
                      min_distance[i] = min_distance[nearest_node] + d;
          }     
   }
} 

 stop = get_time();
 return(stop-start);
}
```

And here the function get_distance with direct_edge_struct structure:

```cs
struct direct_edge_struct {
  int destination_node;
  int weight;
  struct direct_edge_struct *next;
};

int get_distance(int node1, int node2){
  if (node1 == node2)
    return 0;
  struct direct_edge_struct *edge = nodes[node1];
  while (edge != NULL){
    if (edge->destination_node == node2)
      return edge->weight;
    edge = edge->next;
  }
  // node2 has not been found as a direct neighbour of node 1
  return INF;
}
```

I tried to use #pragma omp critical instead of reduction(min) which recover the smallest value of every threads:

```cs
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min : shortest_dist) num_threads(nb)
```

However the running time is pretty high because using a critical section is expensive. I know that creating threads in others threads is a bad idea but I obtained a running time of 0.13-0.14 seconds with this solution whereas the running time of the sequential version is around 0.15 seconds.
Is it possible to get a decent version without modifying the code ?

 Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently I can change the code. Should I try to remove the break ?

Comment: firstprivate(nearest_node) lastprivate(nearest_node)

Comment: I really don't believe that you intend to have each outer thread create a new thread team, each of which then does the whole calculation! (Which is to say that you don't want #pragma omp parallel for inside the omp parallel region...)